# Serving bundle.js in docker

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, docker, webpack

I've been trying to deploy an application to aws for sometime now. My web app works perfectly fine locally, but when it is hosted on aws via a docker container I'm running into the following error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (bundle.js)
or...
GET http://my_AWS_ROUTE_53/bundle.js net::ERR_ABORTED
```

Folder structure:

```
config
--> webpack.config.js    
dist
--> bundle.js
src
--> public (where all of my client code is, also what is producing bundle.js)
    --> index.js
--> server
    --> static
        --> index.html
Dockerfile
app.js
```

Here is how I'm serving my files in app.js:

```
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/src/server/static/'));
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/dist/'));
app.get('/', function (request, response){
    response.sendFile(__dirname + '/src/server/static/index.html'); 
})
```

webpack.config.js for output:

```
entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "../src/public/index.js"),
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist/'),
        publicPath: "/",
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
```

Index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <base href="/" />
  <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="myTestApp"> </div>
</body>
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
</html>
```

I don't know if it is worth noting, but the GET on index.html returns a 304 locally.

I've been wracking my brain over this one for a day or so now. Something tells me I'm doing something silly, but having trouble understanding why it works locally, but not in docker on AWS.

Thanks.

EDIT: Here is my dockerfile

```
FROM node:7.9.0

ENV appDir /var/www/app/current

RUN mkdir -p /var/www/app/current
WORKDIR ${appDir}

ADD package.json ./
RUN npm i

ADD . /var/www/app/current

EXPOSE 3001

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Comment: what does `npm start` do - does it include running webpack? - you may wish to run the build before serving the assets (i.e. starting the server)

Comment: npm start = "node app.js" which starts my express back-end server. So no it does not include running webpack. However, the bundle.js is still in the dist folder, and docker should have access to it when it copies everything in.

Comment: you've only copied the package.json, do local builds (dist/) folder won't be included in the container. - therefore you need to add a command to build `webpack` in your dockerfile for the bundle.js to be found and served. - include it in the dockerfile and this should resolve.

Comment: `ADD . /var/www/app/current` copies everything from the root directory into /var/www/app/current including the dist directory. The only item in my `.dockerignore` file is the node_modules folder.

Comment: `docker exec bash` into the container - and `ls` into that folder (to confirm) - (if so, i'm a bit stumped and will follow for answer)

Comment: So I exec'd into the container locally and I'm able to see everything, including the bundle.js. I also just exec'd into the container in aws and see the same thing, which is the file structure I posted above plus some helpers and a few other folders. 

Haha was really hoping you'd be right :'(, this is a very frustrating issue.

Comment: Do not know if I'm using the right path in index.html for bundle.js: `<script src="bundle.js"></script>`. That's the only thing I can think of at the moment that could be wrong.

Comment: Two questions: 1) what does the log from the container say when you request the file? 2) when you say it works locally, does that mean running the app from the command line or running the docker container?